# FileInputStream can not find file

Tags: java, file, io

File has a new instantiation from the canonical path that returns the list of files wrong.

An FileNotFoundException has occurred java.io.FileNotFoundException

**Java class section**

```
 File file = new File("C:\\Locations.txt");
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

I've also attempted to use FileReader

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Locations.txt")));
```

Still the same result.  The name's there it isn't a problem is the console request finds what I'm parsing through. Any feedback that it's there?

Comment: You're sure the file is at the root of the C drive?

Comment: Print file.isFile(). Also check the extension of File, sometimes case of extension cause this problem.

Comment: @Austin it's impossible to get the information saying the name of the file if it's in a different location.

Comment: What is the error message of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You will find that the problem *actually is* the pathname, one way or another.

When `FileInputStream` attempts to open a file on Windows, it checks if the path is absolute by the following heuristic:

- If the first two characters are `'\\'` - UNC absolute path
- If the 2nd character is a `':'` and the third character is `'\\'` - Absolute path with a drive name.

If the path is absolute (and not too long) then it is passed to the Windows OS to open the file.  That includes a (definitive) check to see whether the file actually exists.

(The above description is based on my reading of the C source code of the for the native code implementation of `FileInputStream.open0` for Windows ... in the OpenJDK source tree for Java 8.)

You have supplied an absolute path (according to the heuristic) and it isn't too long.  So the problem must be that Windows itself thinks that the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo to help you out:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:\\test\\locations.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("does not exist.");
       return;
    }
  if(file.isFile() && file.canRead()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName()+ " can be read from.");
 }
 if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println(file.getPath()+" is a directory containing...");
        String[] files = file.list();
        for (String file1 : files) {
            System.out.println(file1);
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Put a try catch to make things clean .
And for console testing and if you're sure that file will be provided as an argument then here is way :

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
File file = new File(args[0]);
if (!file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File does not exist.");
   return;
}
if(file.isFile() && file.canRead()) {
    System.out.println(file.getName()+ " can be read from.");
}
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println(file.getPath()+" is a directory containing...");
String[] files = file.list();
    for (String file1 : files) {
        System.out.println(file1);
    }
}
} 
}
```